# Transactional Service Method that updates 2 repositories

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, spring-transactions

I want to test Transactional operation in my project. Basically, I want to roll back the `userService.saveUser()` operation, if an exception is thrown. I have simplified the classes, and you can find it below.

A user must live in an address. An address can have multiple users.

Address Entity

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "STREET")
    @NotNull
    private String street;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

User Entity

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Address address;

}
```

Repositories

```
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
}
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

UserService Class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    AddressRepository addressRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(String firstName, String street) {
        var address1 = Address.builder.street(street).build();
        // to make sure that I have "id" of the address when I am saving it.
        var addressSaved = addressRepository.save(address1);
        if ("f1".equals(firstName))
           throw new RuntimeException("some exception");
        var user = User.builder()
                .firstName(firstName)
                .address(addressSaved)
                .build();
        // this operation can also throw DataIntegrityViolationException
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

This is my test class

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    AddressRepository addressRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        addressRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    
    @Test
    void test_saveUser() {
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class,() -> userService.saveUser("f1", "s1"));
        assertEquals(0, userRepository.count());
        assertEquals(0, addressRepository.count());
    }

    @Test
    void test_saveUser2() {
        // column: nullable = false will throw the exception
        assertThrows(DataIntegrityViolationException.class,() -> userService.saveUser(null, "s1"));
        assertEquals(0, userRepository.count());
        assertEquals(0, addressRepository.count());
    }
    
}
```

Both of the tests give assertion error on address count (Address is saved and user is not saved). I expect address to be roll backed (and not to be saved) since there is an error after saving the address, and while saving the user (some condition is violated, therefore 2 saves must be roll backed). What am I doing wrong?

`application.yml` for test environment

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: 123
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    database: H2
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

You can reach the whole sample project from this link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cb870266e2e20f610b44d3cc9f229c220220308071438/7b88a2700076a3e53771e389c796cfe420220308071438/c777ab

Comment: Which database and version are you using? Also your `save` method should be `public` not have a default accessor method like it has now.

Comment: Copy paste error. Save method is indeed public. I am using H2 in test environment.
```type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false driverClassName: org.h2.Driver```

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments as that is totally unreadable and please provide proper code, these are the errors you get if you aren't posting code that you are actually using but a dumbed down version (which is probable part of the issue here and won't lead to an answer).

Comment: I added application.yml in test/resources in the code @M.Deinum

Comment: @covon29619 from the code you posted everything is fine and even I did a quick test on my PC and both unit tests ran successfully. is it possible to share source code?

Comment: @covon29619 you are using `Spring` or `Spring Boot`?

Comment: @hatefalipoor I am using Spring Boot. I have used 2.4.5, 2.6.3 and 2.6.4 versions. Every version fails in those tests

Comment: in my PC everything works fine. @covon29619 is it possible to share original code?

Comment: @hatefalipoor I uploaded the sample project to wetransfer and shared the link in the post. Can you look into that?

Comment: @covon29619 sure, I will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted here differs from what is actually exists in the original code you uploaded.

original code:

```
@Transactional
void saveUser(String firstName, String street) {
    var address = Address.builder().street(street).build();
    var addressSaved = addressRepository.save(address);

    if ("f1".equals(firstName))
        throw new RuntimeException("f1");

    var user = Person.builder()
            .firstName(firstName)
            .address(addressSaved)
            .build();
    personRepository.save(user);
}
```

This method actually have default access modifier so `CGLIB` is not able to override it and creates the needed logic. change access modifier of this method to `public`

Comment: Thank you! Since I have changed the code too many times, I guess there was a difference between what I pasted in here and what I provided. That solved my issue.